# Illustrator opens images with a black square

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hi whenever I open a picture in Illustrator it opens with a black square in the middle. Any Ideas as to why it's doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the artboard. From what I can tell, if you open an image directly in Illustrator it creates the artboard at the same size as the last document you created. If you are working with images in Illustrator, the best option is to create a document at the size you need then place any images in the document.

To fit the artboard to the image all you need to do is select the artboard tool and double click the image. Or select the image and go to `Object -> Artboards -> Fit to Selected Art`.